# Posting to custom port from Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I get a `503 service unavailable` response when I post to an endpoint listening on a custom port from within an Azure Function.

I checked the Network Settings for the function but couldn't find any option to "open" ports.

Is it not possible to `POST` to a custom port from within Azure Function?

Comment: What is that custom endpoint ? Is it some azure service,webapp..

Comment: @RahulRuikar yes it is an endpoint running on an Azure VM. The DNS and the IP address are part of a Network group on which that PORT is set to allow all incoming and outgoing requests. Also, I can post to the end point from POSTMAN directly.

Answer (score 1):

1. while creating virtual machine, in networking tab you can specify inbound/outbound ports to open.
2. Create function app in "App service plan" as consumption plan does not support vNet integration.
3. Under platform features -> Networking , configure vNet integration by specifying subnet to connect to the subnet of virtual machine.

Sample configuration to create this connectivity is provided here in Azure functions documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

Comment: @RahilRuikar Thanks for the info and the links. Looks like the portal has changed and there's no VNEt confit option. I do see an `Access Restrictions` option that currently has only 1 rule to allow everything from all sources and ports.

Comment: Ok. I will try myself and let you know today

Comment: I double checked the function and it wasn't defined under an App Service plan. Created another one but no luck with VNet integration. However, created new function with consumption plan, without any triggers but setup the proxy to post to destination URL (one I was trying to post to from an HTTP Trigger, unsuccessfully) and it works. Basically, a Function app with no code but acting as a facade. Thanks for your pointers.